# Android app not visible in google play if open in samsung 10 inch tab

Tags: android, visible

I uploaded app on google play i can see my app in google play web site, mostly all mobile and tablet but when i see my app in google play in samsung tab 10 inch, its not visible. i tried a lot using support-screen and screen compatible property in manifest file but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i faced this problem. Actually on the basis of declaration in manifest google play filters the application and i have take camera permission but not include camera feature thats why google play filter my application and not showing in google play when i use samsung galaxy tab 10 inch. so i also declare camera feature in manifest and mention it required false. i hope it will solve your problem.